# Rails Tutorial の Chapter 6 で User が作成出来ない

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Rails Tutorial の Chapter 6 ([日本語訳](http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/modeling-users?version=4.0#sec-user_model)) を進めています。

コンソールを見るとユーザーが作成されているようなのですが、

`Couldn't find User with id=1`

とエラーを吐いてしまう理由をご教授頂きたいです。

---

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

  def new

  end

end
```

---

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

---

rails console --sandboxの結果

```
2.0.0-p481 :007 > User.find(1)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<User id: 2, name: "testuesr", email: "test@example.com", created_at: "2015-01-01 13:28:14", updated_at: "2015-01-01 13:28:14", password_digest: "$2a$10$XHiVgRQlirrbx8oehDGii.Ko/Vi8NHaud920gniw6RFy...">
```

---

user table

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps

    end

  end

end
```

---

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150101022243) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 3):

サンドボックスモードのコンソール上でユーザーを作成しているためと考えられます。

6.3.5 節にあるように、 `rails console` でコンソールを起動し、ユーザーを作成するとブラウザ上からも確認できるはずです。

`--sandbox` を付けてコンソールを起動すると、DBへの書き込みがすべてトランザクション内でおこなわれるので、コンソール外からは変更が見えません。またコンソールを終了した時点ですべての変更が取り消しになります。([関連ソースコード](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L58))

Answer (score 1):

登録されているUserのidが2になってしまっていますね。

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

してDBの状態を初期状態に戻した後に、再度`irb`（あるいは`pry`など）で

```
user = User.new(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com")
user.save
```

などとするのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: dbを初期状態に戻して、
`User.create(name: "testuesr", email: "test@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")`

をして、User.find(1)を実行すると登録されているのが確認出来るのですが、ブラウザ上だと同様のエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: そういうことでしたか。`rails console --sandbox`はあくまでサンドボックスですので、Webアプリ実行時にはUserテーブルにデータが入っていないのかなと思いました。`user_controller.rb`にユーザ数を返す簡単なメソッドを実装してWeb側からDBの状態を確認するなどしてみるのはどうでしょうか。
尚、ユーザ登録部分はチュートリアルの7章で実装するみたいですので、そちらを実装してからWebブラウザで確認するというのでも良い気がします。

Comment: 丁寧に教えて下さいまして、ありがとうございました。
無事解決出来ました。